# How to fix google sign In option function getting duplicate and crash when switching between tablayout

Tags: java, android, google-signin

//This is code I put in fragment to login using google button, but when I switching between tab it's say gso getting duplicated

```
 //Google
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
        // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity()/*FragmentActivity*/, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        // your code here
                    }
                })
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

//This is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.indofun.android.indojoy, PID: 29659
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already managing a GoogleApiClient with id 0
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:29)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaj.zaa(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.build(Unknown Source:135)
    at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Support.LoginFirstFragment.onCreateView(LoginFirstFragment.java:227)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

> V//b/: 3 enc
>   AgGQdDMuiDfQ5lI0RVVyNxy8sOmjBU/8FMfb2Hetx2w7P1wKPsELt9r6l7x6+bh7F2A4Be99mxObTv+jUiJMHj+OhSyp79RUYyQN6WIogY6QGVjByBBHBk1X8GuF2SuJ8Qt/+VnCh2NwXrqfTLpZIY96iafHP37i83fbJe2e6fo2Hp8jIr50SHOwwtWAMHM+dLE=
>       rncryptor_process ow passwordf: a598cfba8ce19716ee349a56a2070695
>       rncryptor_process ow strf: {"sdk_key":"T9AvaPr0","app":"IDJY","id_user":"Ga ada ID USER USER"}
>        rncryptorUpdateProfile AgGQdDMuiDfQ5lI0RVVyNxy8sOmjBU/8FMfb2Hetx2w7P1wKPsELt9r6l7x6+bh7F2A4Be99mxObTv+jUiJMHj+OhSyp79RUYyQN6WIogY6QGVjByBBHBk1X8GuF2SuJ8Qt/+VnCh2NwXrqfTLpZIY96iafHP37i83fbJe2e6fo2Hp8jIr50SHOwwtWAMHM+dLE=
>   V//b/: okHttpClient_call s_u http://api.indojoy.id/1.0/profile/load
>   V//b/: ViewProfileResponse: {"s":0,"d":{"ec":-1021,"m":"Invalid
>   id_user, user not found."}}
>        doAPIIndojoy onResponse ResponseValid 0
>        Webapi doAPIIndojoy(); e org.json.JSONException: No value for name
>        doAPIIndojoy onResponse HitCallback {"s":0,"d":{"ec":-1021,"m":"Invalid id_user, user not found."}}
>        doAPIIndojoy onResponse HitResponseResponse{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://api.indojoy.id/1.0/profile/load}
>   I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false E/cr_PlatformSer-Internal:
>   UsageReporting query failed

Answer (score 0):

I got it you need to activated it when press google button not when you create the View, thank you